# git checkout code until chapter 8 of Michael Hart's book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, github, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been to trying to learn ruby on rails tutorial from
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

I completed chapter 8 , but along the way I made some errors in my rpsec and the controller.
I should have updated my git repo regularly, but I did not.
Is there a way I can checkout the code until Chapter8 of the book?

I want to continue to practice from Chapter 9, but I want to make sure I have the correct code until chapter 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, Hartl does not provide a git repository of the code used in the book.

Comment: I think you've learned an important lesson with SCM. @maro's answer should get you to a good state. You can work backwards from the finished repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download full repository of this tutorial directly from [Github.](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app)

Do the following steps:

1. `mkdir new_dir_name`  create a new directory
2. inside this directory : 
   `git clone git@github.com:railstutorial/sample_app.git`

result:
you will find the source code in your directory and then you can continue.